How to select pseudo element in react typescript using useRef
I'm trying to select pseudo element in React typescript.
define ref
 const header = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
set ref
<div className={classNames(style.header)} ref={header}>
but I don't know how to select pseudo element of header.current?.
please help me.
Thanks

If you make it more clear about what do you want to achieve, I would like to help

You can't; pseudo elements are not DOM elements. They are just styling trickery.

This may be an XY problem. It would be useful to clarify why you think you need to select a pseudo-element. Depending on what you need to do with it the correct approach may be something other than selecting it.
